# How to extract password protected files from FreeArc archive using Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I have made an Inno Setup installer and I have compressed installation files using FreeArc and have added a password to it but I don't know how to extract these files using my setup because I don't know the code for extracting password protected files.

So, please help me with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the (Russian) [FreeArc command-line documentation](https://freearc.sourceforge.net/rus/FreeArc040-rus.htm#_Toc185594991).

It seems the argument to use is `-p password`.